# How to stop a batch of proxies request to server?

Tags: extjs4

I'm using Extjs4 MVC pattern. My problem is, i want to cancel or stop a mount of proxies (ajax) request to server. on the store page, even i set config as autoload = false which never meet my logic.

Comment: try with setting batchActions : false in proxy config. refer below sencha doc for reference http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy-cfg-batchActions

Comment: Still not work :( my problem can said Ext.ajax.abort() but  i still got problem